# Marklogic - xdmp:eval generates errors such as "Invalid options node"

Tags: marklogic

Marklogic 7, Windows 7.

I'm trying to write Xquery to change the URIs of documents (local version of ML) using the `xdmp:load` and `xdmp:delete` functions in a single transaction.

I've finally settled on using `xdmp:eval`. What's generating the error?

Code follows :-

```
for $SrcFileNode in xdmp:directory("/Abstracts/", "infinity") [position() lt 10]
(: get filename from path string :)
let $Filename := (if (fn:contains(fn:document-uri($SrcFileNode),".zip/")) 
                  then fn:substring-after(document-uri($SrcFileNode),".zip/") 
                  else fn:substring-after(document-uri($SrcFileNode),"Loadrecords/") 
                  )

(: create new URI would "document{...}" be better? :)
let $newURInode := xdmp:unquote(
                                fn:concat('<options xmlns="xdmp:document-load"><uri>/Abstracts/'
                                          ,$Filename,'</uri><repair>none</repair><permissions>'
                                          ,xdmp:default-permissions(),'</permissions><collections><collection>'
                                          ,'Abstracts','</collection></collections></options>')
                                )

(: get string of node's name :)
let $SrcFileStr := xdmp:quote(fn:document-uri($SrcFileNode))

(: build a string of the copy + delete actions in a single transaction as applied to the current file. Implement the action using "xdmp:eval" :)
let $LoadDelCMD :=  'xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
                    declare option xdmp:transaction-mode "update";
                    xdmp:document-load($SrcFileStr,$newURInode);
                    xdmp:document-delete($SrcFileStr);
                    xdmp:commit()'

(: execute the copy/delete for the current document :) 

(: 1st attempt... 
return xdmp:eval($LoadDelCMD,(),<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"> <isolation>different-transaction</isolation> <prevent-deadlocks>true</prevent-deadlocks></options> ) 
:)

(: 2nd attempt...
let $Option  := document{<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation> <prevent-deadlocks>true</prevent-deadlocks></options>}
return xdmp:eval($LoadDelCMD,(),$Option)
:)

(: 3rd attempt...
let $Option2 := xdmp:unquote('<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"> <isolation>different-transaction</isolation> <prevent-deadlocks>true</prevent-deadlocks></options>')
return xdmp:eval($LoadDelCMD,(),$Option2) 
:)
```

Comment: The errors are...."[1.0-ml] XDMP-INVOPTNOD: xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;; &#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9; ...", (), document{<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation><prevent-deadlocks>t...</options>}) -- Invalid options node: fn:doc("")"    OR     "[1.0-ml] XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found '"' (0x0022) 
At line 3 column 58"
At line 48 column 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the error itself, it is complaining about `$Option` which contains an options element wrapped in a document node. Get rid of the document node by removing the document node constructor. It you pull the options from a file, you can unwrap it by adding `/*` behind it.

Apart from that I think you are making things more complicated than necessary. If you just want to update the document, then no need for a delete, just insert or load to the same uri again. If you want to move a doc to a different spot, simply do the insert/load in the same transaction as the delete. As long as there are no inserts/loads/deletes applied to the same uri, no conflicting updates will occur, and all is persisted at the same time, at the successful end of the code.

You are not the first that is looking to move/rename documents in a database. Here link to a nice helper function to move docs within a database:

http://markmail.org/message/2e5wu3sqgpiwnu5m

Oh, by the way, your eval is loading and deleting the same uri. That doesn't sound like changing the uris of documents..

HTH!

Comment: "grtn". Thank you for the link. The code's only purpose is to move documents from uri 1 to uri 2. The reason for using the eval was as a way to run the insert and delete tasks as consecutive actions within a transaction (an idea pulled from an earlier StackOverflow).  All 3 'return' options seem to generate errors even the one using xdmp:eval($LoadCmd,(),<options>...</options>) syntax. I'll take a closer look at the element wrapped in a node issue you mentioned.  I'll have another go without the eval and see if I can get that "playing ball".

Comment: Using the rename function I referred to above is probably the fastest and safest way to move documents to different uris. And as explained you don't need to delete and insert in different statements, so no need for the explicit transactional hassle. A single statement is already fully ACID transactional..